# How delete singel word from dataframe except few define words like *when what*

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How delete singel word from dataframe except few define words like *when what*

```
1.  Hello
2. My name is khan
3. When
4. What
5. Opted bat
6. Learn
```

*I want output like*

```
2. My name is khan
3. When
4. What
5. Opted bat
```

Comment: Question is not clear enough!!! Provide more details. You said you want to delete *when what* but these words still appear in your output.

Comment: Yes that words are predefine which should come in output other than that i have to delete all singel word like hello and learn

Comment: Provide predefined list for above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filtering multiple words chained by `bitwise OR` with mask for filtering words defined in list:

```
words = ['When','What']

df = df[(df['col'].str.split().str.len() != 1) | df['col'].isin(words)]
print (df)
               col
1  My name is khan
2             When
3             What
4        Opted bat
```

If words are defined lowercase in list:

```
words = ['when','what']
df = df[(df['col'].str.split().str.len() != 1) | df['col'].str.lower().isin(words)]
```